# Not able to display component via routing in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-routing, angular-components

I have 3 components: A, B, and C. I want to display a button named "Component B" inside component A. On clicking the button, it should display B component with a link saying "Component C". On clicking the link it should display c component which says "C component works"

The app module is:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AComponent } from './a/a.component';
import { BComponent } from './b/b.component';
import { CComponent } from './c/c.component';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        AComponent,
        BComponent,
        CComponent
    ],
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule
],
providers: [],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

The app routing module is:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { AComponent } from './a/a.component';
import { BComponent } from './b/b.component';
import { CComponent } from './c/c.component';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';


const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'a',
    component: AComponent,
  },
  {
    path: 'a',
    component: BComponent,

  },
  {
    path: 'c', component: CComponent
  },
  { 
    path: '**', component: AppComponent 
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

The app.component.html is :

```
<h3>Routing and Navigation</h3>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

The A component is:

```
<h4>It is Component A</h4>
<a class="button" routerLink="a" routerLinkActive='active'>B component</a>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

The B component is:

```
<a routerLink="b">C component</a>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

The C component is:

```
<p>C component works</p>
```

Kindly help me with this as I am learning to route in Angular. I will be glad if I know the area of improvement in the code and a proper guidance. Thank you.

Comment: will these components be shown in the same window? like button A then under it button B then under it C component works ?

Comment: The path for `BComponent` should be `'b'`, not `'a'`

Comment: @MjJameel yes it must be shown under same window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a stackBlitz with a working example that has all 3 components.

https://angular-7ucy2h.stackblitz.io/a

the thing about angular routing is that if you want a child route to show inside of a parent route you will have to add that route as a child.

in your case C is a child of B and B is a child of A.

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'a',
    component: AComponent,
    children: [
      {path: 'b', component: BComponent, children: [
        {path: 'c', component: CComponent}
      ]},
    ]
  },
];
```

Comment: The link doesn't work. Can you send it again if you have?

Comment: thats weird i just tried it again the link works for me. here try again. https://angular-7ucy2h.stackblitz.io/a

Comment: Also are there any error in other component because I implemented the child routes as you said but still I am not getting the output.

Comment: are you able to see the stackblitz now  or? try this link. it lets you see each component and how its written.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7ucy2h. and no the stackBlitz I made has no errors

Comment: please keep in mind that your app-component.html must have a <router-outlet></router-outlet> same goes for your A and B components.

Comment: Thank you for the help. Solves a bit. I guess I need to brainstorm and read more. Can you also share me some nice resources to learn angular. It will be very helpful.

Comment: I mostly started learning on youtube. but the best thing for me was buying a class on udemy.com that helped so much

Answer (score 0):

You don't need routing at all to do what you are asking. If Component B & C are "inside" component A, then you don't route to them. you just display them.

```
<h4>It is Component A</h4>
<a class="button" (click)="showBFlg = true">B component</a>

<div *ngIf="showBFlg">
    <app-b></app-b>
    <a class="button" (click)="showCFlg = true">C component</a>
</div>

<app-c *ngIf="showCFlg"></app-c>
```

Comment: yes but in many cases developer want things separated by routes maybe this is one of them

Comment: Separate routes can be very useful to end users because they allow you to bookmark more specific pages, share links to specific things, etc